# Regex required to update a character

Tags: java, regex

I have a String : *`testing<b>s<b>tringwit<b>h</b>nomean<b>s</b>ing`*

I want to replace the character **s** with some other character sequence suppose : `<b>X</b>` but i want the character sequence **s** to remain intact i.e. regex should not update the character s with a previous character as "<".

I used the JAVA code :

```
String str = testing<b>s<b>tringwit<b>h</b>nomean<b>s</b>ing;
str = str.replace("s[^<]", "<b>X</b>");
```

The problem is that the regex would match 2 characters, s and following character if it is not ">" and **Sting.replace** would replace both the characters. I want only **s** to be replaced and not the following character.

Any help would be appreciated. Since i have lots of such replacements i don't want to use a loop matching each character and updating it sequentially.

Comment: i think you mean `str.replaceAll`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
s(?!<)
```

---

```
String str = "testing<b>s<b>tringwit<b>h</b>nomean<b>s</b>ing;";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("s(?!<)", "<b>X</b>"));
```

output:

```
te<b>X</b>ting<b>s<b>tringwit<b>h</b>nomean<b>s</b>ing;
```

Comment: Yes that solved the problem. Thanks a lot. I would be accepting the answer in 10 mins. stackoverflow wont let me accept before that :)

Answer (score 2):

There are other ways, but you could, for example, capture the second character and put it back:

```
str = str.replaceAll("s([^<])", "<b>X\\1</b>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use look arounds to assert, but not capture, surrounding text:

```
str = str.replaceAll("s(?![^<]))", "whatever");
```

Or, capture and put back using a back reference `$1`:

```
str = str.replaceAll("s([^<])", "whatever$1");
```

Note that you need to use `replaceAll()` (which use regex), rather than `replace()` (which uses plain text).